# Generate random numbers excluding numbers on a range

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

I used AGGREGATE to generate random numbers between 1-6 excluding the ones listed on a range in excel.
I tried to use the AGGREGATE function in google sheets but it somehow doesn't work. Since AGGREAGTE doesn't work, is there a way to achieve the same result without using the aggregate function?
Im trying to generate random numbers between 1-6 in range Q7:Q12. But the random number generator should exclude numbers that are on P7:P12. I appreciate everyone's help. Thanks in advance.

The sheet is on the link below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Q3NwiK7QeedHC6mImnt34iS2lYpcSaTdGygulSvMQI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**First answer assuming that number in Q should different than number to the left in P**

Try this:

Assuming that you have a number in P9 you can write in Q9:

```
    =iferror(
index(
   query({1;2;3;4;5;6},"select * where Col1 <> "&P9),
randbetween(1,5)))
```

This formula consists of 3 stages:

1. QUERY makes a table of one column with numbers from 1 to 6, but number from P9 is excluded from it.
2. Random index is chosen from this table (there should be 5 indexes when we remove one that is equal to P9)
3. Iferror protects formula against situations when P9 does not contain number.

[image]

**Edit:
Second answer assuming that number in Q must be different than all the numbers in P**

This case is a bit complicated. Especially when empty cells in P only seem to be empty (in some cases some invisible content appears there).

As previously we have to make a list of numbers from 1 to 6 and exclude numbers found in column P. There are max. 2 numbers now. And this answer will work only with 2 numbers.

I do query to my manually made list and exclude 1st and 2nd index of P7:P12 list of numbers, then I randomly choose an index from a shortened list:

```
=
index(
   query({1;2;3;4;5;6},"select * where 
        Col1 <> "&index(query($P$7:$P$12,"select * where P >0",0),1)&" and 
        Col1 <> "&index(query($P$7:$P$12,"select * where P >0",0),2)
    ,0),
randbetween(1,4))
```

You can find a working example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHE8_HTGHRKWu5tX501um41P-a98ZUhdimRzfy9NEks/copy

Comment: thank you for looking into this. however, range Q7:Q12 should still display randomly generated numbers from 1-6 (excluding 1 & 2 from range P7:P12). I have put examples on the same sample sheet for reference.

Comment: @Richard - Please check my answer now.